# How to handle url change when a node dies?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. I have a cluster with 3 nodes on a same machine. To access each node I have separate url as the port changes(localhost:9200, localhost:9201, localhost:9202).

Now the question I have is that suppose my node 1(i.e. master node) dies then elasticsearch engine handle the situation very well and makes node 2 as master node but how does my application know that a node died and now I need to hit node 2 with port 9201?

Is there a way using which I always hit a single URL and internally it figures out which node to hit?

Thanks,
Pratz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client search nodes with a discovery module. The name of the cluster in your clients configuration is important to get this working.

With a correct configuration (on client and cluster) you can bring a single node down without any (negative) effect on your client.

See the following links:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your links helped me in learning about modules discovery.

I think I asked this question in very early stage of my learning. I actually wanted to use elastic search with java and I asked this question before reading elasticsearch java client api.
After using java client even if the server is down elasticsearch is returning results fine and determines internally from which node to respond. I have used elasticsearch's transportClient.

-Pratz